# Why Is .html File In Root Directory Not Rendering In Browser? Shows Index Of/

Tags: ftp, html, redirection, htaccess, home-directory

Hello I just have a simple `.html` file in the root directory of my site:

[image]

But when I visit that site in the browser,

it's showing me `index of/` and I have to click on `test.html` in order to display the page properly:

[image]

(and then after clicking on `test.html`)

[image]

Any idea why it's showing the `test.html` file first and then I have to click on it in order to get the page to display properly?

This is the only file in the directory.

Thanks.

Comment: What server are you using? If you're going to ask & answer, then please provide pertinent details, and perhaps also anonymize the domain and include more basic example data. This isn't related to any of your tagged topics, so please fix that too.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to change `test.html` to `index.html` or put the following code in your `.htaccess` file:

`DirectoryIndex test.html`

Answer (score 0):

Works Perfectly fine on my Chrome Browser.

Have you tried clearing the cache and then retrying?
I've had a similar issue because of the browser cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I posted a solution below. I just wanted to ask this question anyway to hopefully help others who are having the same issue.